Implementing both base and derived interfaces
interface IBaseInterface
{
}

interface IDerivedInterface1 : IBaseInterface
{
}


class MyClass1 :
    IDerivedInterface1
{
}

class MyClass2 :
    IDerivedInterface1,
    IBaseInterface
{
}

Is there any advantage or disadvantage of MyClass2 over MyClass1?
When should we or should not derive a class like MyClass2?

The only difference I can think of is the readability difference. Do you want to IBaseInterface to be implicit for shorter/simpler code, or explicit for better clarity? Is it obvious to the reader that IDerivedInterface1 inherits from IBaseInterface ?

From the language specification:

A class or struct that directly implements an interface also implicitly implements all of the interface’s base interfaces. This is true even if the class or struct doesn’t explicitly list all base interfaces in the base class list.

So the obvious statement to make here is that if you want to implement one or more of the interfaces explicitly, then you need to name those interfaces in your base class list.
Otherwise, if you're just using implicit interface implementations, then the compiled output should be the same whether or not you named the base interfaces.

"if you want to implement one or more of the interfaces explicitly" that doesn't seem true https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFAEsB2AXApgJwGYCGAxlgAQCSAQgQM5bma6EnIDeypnpUALKQGIB7QQAoAlAG5kAX2TJ02fMTLkAIrhQA3LMAaLmWOKRAVqdPU2VsZcpMlikAsgE8AwgBtaNIyA5c1Gtq6jEokiEjsSFzcfFS09CEGAHRComKkrLJIWfYwTm6eNDR5vlH+6jhaOhahhgA0fpxx5olWEY0xpvE1yaniGVlZQA
